# documenting CSV data, using python

Tags: python, csv, documentation, graphing, measurement

0. Not sure this is the right place to ask, but it has to be a common problem.
1. I'm collecting AC voltage(real, apparent, etc.) vs. an input parameter to measure the performance of a solar inverter. I read data from a meter, the invert, and other test equipment and then write the data to a CSV file for later plotting. The details here are not important except to say that part works.
2. There are various modes available with their own values that I want to record with the data.  I.e., I might set the foo-parameter to 0.5 and then record the complex voltage output versus the DC input.  I need to do this for several values of the foo-parameter, and many parameters should be recorded.
3. I've modified my plot routine to allow *#comment lines*.  This will allow me to record the parameters that were selected for any data set.

***Is there a standard way of doing this, or otherwise documenting data collected like this?***

Comment: Sounds like you need a DB to store data and then export it to CSV for plotting.

Comment: The  comment from @PM77-1 is the best solution. If you want to stick with CSV only then  columns that hold the parameter type and values.

Comment: That should have been *... then add columns...*.

Comment: @PM77-1, thanks for the comment, but I want to avoid that as I don't know how long this data needs to persist.  
It occurs to me that if I am going to do something non-standard, I should not call it CSV data., but provide a tool to convert CCSV (commented CSV) to CSV.
Adding columns seems more problematic than adding comment lines.  
I'm still prototyping, and I'm trying to minimize the code I write.  Hence, wondering if there are tools out there that solves this problem.

Comment: 1) Why does the persistence time matter? Writing/reading to file or to a database table is basically the same and you can delete data from either. 2) In Python you have a built in database [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) so the only thing you have to do is `import` the module into your code.

Comment: @adrianklaver it requires yet another tool. Or it is opaque too others.